# Resolve metadata displayname from model metadata?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper

I have made a label extension with an additional parameter but when I use ViewData.ModelMetadata.DisplayName I don't get the display name from the Diaplsy attribute on my model?

My model has a username like this

```
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
```

and is used like this

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.SetupModel.UserName, @<span>No fancy characters mmkay?</span>)
```

with this html helper

```
    public static MvcHtmlString LabelFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> ex, Func<object, HelperResult> template, string labelText = null) {
        var htmlFieldName = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(ex);
        var metadata = htmlHelper.ViewData.ModelMetadata;
        string resolvedLabelText = labelText ?? metadata.DisplayName ?? metadata.PropertyName ?? htmlFieldName.Split('.').Last();
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(resolvedLabelText)) {
            return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
        }

        var tag = new TagBuilder("label");
        tag.Attributes.Add("for", TagBuilder.CreateSanitizedId(htmlHelper.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(htmlFieldName)));
        tag.InnerHtml = string.Format(
            "{0} {1}",
            resolvedLabelText,
            template(null).ToHtmlString()
        );
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(tag.ToString());
    }
```

But the result is UserNameNo fancy characters mmkay? when I thought it should show the name set in the display attribute?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I missed the fact that you have different objects inside your viewmodel when I posted my previous answer. The following is just to illustrate the idea, there should be a better way to do this.

This is the trick:

```
var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(ex, htmlHelper.ViewData);
var resolvedLabelText = labelText ?? metadata.DisplayName ?? metadata.PropertyName ?? htmlFieldName.Split('.').Last();
```

```
string resolvedLabelText = "";
if (htmlFieldName.Contains('.'))
{
    var model = htmlFieldName.Split('.');

    var metadata = htmlHelper.ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties.FirstOrDefault(p => p.PropertyName == model[0] );
    if (metadata != null)
    {
        metadata = metadata.Properties.FirstOrDefault(p => p.PropertyName == model[1]);
        resolvedLabelText = labelText ?? metadata.DisplayName ?? metadata.PropertyName ?? htmlFieldName.Split('.').Last();
    }
    else
        resolvedLabelText = labelText ?? metadata.DisplayName ?? metadata.PropertyName ?? htmlFieldName.Split('.').Last();
}
else 
{
    var metadata = htmlHelper.ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties.First(p => p.PropertyName == htmlFieldName);
    resolvedLabelText = labelText ?? metadata.DisplayName ?? metadata.PropertyName ?? htmlFieldName.Split('.').Last();
}
```

The above will not work for `SomeObject.SomeObject.Propery` for instance.

Comment: I get a Sequence contains no matching element exception because the model I use in this view is of type SetupViewModel which contains a Configuration model and a RegisterModel. The suggested code query's a property namned "SetupModel.UserName".
    public class SetupViewModel {
        public Configuration.Configuration Configuration { get; set; }
        public RegisterModel SetupModel { get; set; }
    }

Comment: I updated my answer, it's just to put you on the right track, it will work in your example, but that's it. The metadata is nested so to say...

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. As you said, it feels like there must be a better way of doing this so it also works on any property.

Comment: Found a better way to get the metadata, so I updated the answer, again.

Answer (score 4):

Just in case in MVC4 its very simple

```
@ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName
@ViewData.ModelMetadata.DisplayName
```